# how to delete 30 day old data using PHP

Tags: php, wpdb, sql

I am mysql beginner, how to delete 30 day old data using php?
This code is not working?

```
global $wpdb;
$table = $wpdb->prefix . "userinfo"; 
$delete_rows ="DELETE * FROM $table WHERE timeall <".strtotime('-1 month');
$wpdb->query($table, $delete_rows);
```

my data photo 1
[image]

my data photo 2
[image]

Comment: I don't see anything WordPress specific.

Comment: Looks like you're not selecting your table correctly. `$wpdb->prefix . "wp_userinfo"` would equate to wp_wp_userinfo. If you're using $wpdb->prefix, you don't need to add the prefix yourself. Just change to `$wpdb->prefix . "userinfo"`

Comment: If this is your userinfo table, you've made some serious modifications to the table structure O.o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding an extra `wp_` prefix to your table and your using a timestamp instead of a MYSQL datetime. Below is how WP suggests you use `$wpdb->query` to delete rows, taken from the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Running_General_Queries).

**EDITED**

```
global $wpdb;

$wpdb->query(
  "DELETE FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "userinfo
   WHERE timeall < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)"
);
```

`$wpdb->prefix` adds the `wp_` for you.

Comment: answer updated with the correct sql query